# how to check the data type of dbt macro function argument?

Tags: macros, jinja2, dbt

I have a simple dbt macro function

```
{% macro test_func(
  arg1="col1",
  arg2=list_of_values
) %}
{{ log("Arg1:" ~ arg1, True) }}
{{ log("Arg2:" ~ arg2, True) }}
{{ log("data type of Arg2:" ~ type(arg2), True)}}

{% endmacro %}
```

Basically i wanted to use `type(arg2)` to check the data type of that argument?

Answer (score 1):

The answer relies purely on Jinja2 syntax.

You can test your arguments data types this way (as per the [Jinja2 documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests), example if you're expecting `Arg2` to be an integer):

```
{% macro test_func(
  arg1="col1",
  arg2=list_of_values
) %}
{{ log("Arg1:" ~ arg1, True) }}
{{ log("Arg2:" ~ arg2, True) }}
{{ log("Is Arg2 an integer: " ~ arg2 is integer, True)}}

{% endmacro %}
```